# sbt mulit-project import error

Tags: sbt, multi-project

I am trying to setup a multi-project that includes a sub-project that does an import of a class that is defined in a Dependencies.scala file in its project directory. When I run sbt on the sub-project everything is fine but when I run sbt on the root project I get an error stating that Dependencies is not found. Here is my root build.sbt:

```
name         := "sbtTest"

organization := "com.test"

version      := "0.1"



lazy val foo = project
```

Here is foo's build.sbt:

```
import Dependencies._

name := "foo"

version := "0.2"


scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
```

Dependencies.scala is in foo/projects and here is the exact error I get:

```
/Users/xyz/git/sbtTest/foo/build.sbt:1: error: not found: object Dependencies

import Dependencies._
       ^
[error] Type error in expression
```

Has anyone run into this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by making my build.sbt look like this..

```
lazy val otherProject = RootProject(file("../otherproject"))

lazy val rootProject = (project in file("."))
    // dependsOn allows the root project to use functions from
    .dependsOn(otherProject)
    // aggregation runs tasks of root project on aggregated projects as well
    .aggregate(otherProject)
```

Comment: I tried this but project foo does not get included when I use RootProject. If I compile foo does not compile and if I run 'sbt projects' foo is not listed.

Comment: You will need .dependsOn and .aggregate on your root project. I will edit my answer with the whole solution.

Answer (score -1):

In sbt you can also define all dependencies in a separated file. 
This file tends to be in /project/Dependencies.scala In the same directory than plugins.sbt.

Then import Dependencies._ can be easy imported in build.sbt  file.